# How to give gaps in X-axis in frappe charts

Tags: javascript, html, charts

Actually I was making line graphs using [frappe-charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfUiG.png). On the X-axis, I have values from 1 to 53 (number of weeks in a year) and on the Y-axis and user's contribution on the y-axis. But since 1 to 53 entries are pretty ackward to show on the X-axis, So I wanted gaps in between the graphs some thing like this:
[image]

But my graph is something like this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```js
let lineGraph = new Chart({
        parent: "#notes", 
        type: "line", 
        show_dots: 0,
        heatline: 1,
        height: 115,
        region_fill: 1, 
        data: data,
        x_axis_mode: "tick",
        y_axis_mode: "span",
        is_series: 1
    });
```

```html
<div id="notes"></div>
```

I have tried to increase is_series to 5 but it's of no use.

Comment: Looking at their source code, it looks like `is_series` is just a flag to indicate that they can remove some values.  But then they calculate the amount of space required and only remove values if necessary.  I didn't see an option to change that behavior in my brief search.

Comment: But in the above picture I can see the value of 1973 which is not specified in the X-axis. I am not able to find out how they are doing this.

Comment: Also one thing I have to give some X-axis label and corresponding value to it. Is there any to miss some X labels in between.

Comment: They remove the skipped values automatically *only* if there is not enough space for all the values. I didn't see a way to do it yourself.  You can look at the code yourself [here](https://github.com/frappe/charts/blob/master/src/js/charts/AxisChart.js), lines 136-188

Comment: okk thanks for your help @LazyElephant

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, just to be precise, I've been having the same issue recently and started digging in the documentation which didn't actually help that much.
Took me a while to figure out.

```js
let lineGraph = new frappe.Chart("#notes",{
    title: "",
    type: 'line',
    height: 115,
    data: data,
    axisOptions: {
        xIsSeries: true,   //default:false
        xAxisMode: "tick",
        yAxisMode: "span"
    },
    lineOptions: {
        hideDots: 1,   //default:0
        heatline: 1,
        regionFill: 1
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="notes"></div>
```

I referred [this](https://frappe.io/charts/docs) but i don't think this actually helps, some explanations are hard to figure out because.. i dunno, it's just hard... and it was the only documentation i found to be helpful.

**Note:** This syntax is from frappe-charts v1.6.2(stable) in case you ask.

Comment: Does this actually solve the problem?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller Yes, this did solve the problem. I've tested it out and it worked perfectly fine.